# Firestore document cannot be written

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem by writing data to `firestore`, I have created an array with data which should be uploaded but I got this error code:

[image]

the code:

```
      var vm = this

      var allRates = {
        createdOn: vm.createdOn,
        rate: vm.rating,
        userId: vm.currentUser.uid,
        content: vm.content,
        name: vm.userProfile.name,
        image: vm.userProfile.userImage
      }

      fb.usersCollection.doc(vm.$route.params.uid).update({
        gotRates: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(allRates)
      })
      .then(rout => {
        console.log('work')
        vm.$router.replace('/world')
      })
```

I have figured out that when I put out the `image: vm.userProfile.userImage` the upload is working, but why not with the image?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the contents of `vm.userProfile.userImage`?  Please be specific.

Comment: I will add a picture above

Comment: You are storing the entire contents of an image (encoded as base64) in the database.  That's not a good idea.

Comment: oh okay, can you explaine why? and how can I do better?

Comment: I think the existing answer here explains what you could do differently.

Comment: okay good to know, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write an image (or PDF) to Firestore. It's a data only database. You will need to store the image in Firebase Storage:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

What you will end up saving to Firestore is a url that links to the image in Firebase Storage.

Here is some info about Firestore/Firebase usage and limits:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: and the  userImage is aleady store in firestore

Comment: I want to store it a second time but in another collection

Comment: and if I run firebase deploy and open my site I can upload it correctly

Comment: Your error says 'exceeds maximum size allowed.' I'm guessing your image file size is too big. Regarding previously saving images to Firestore, I'm wasn't aware that was possible.

Comment: How can be the image size too big if the image is already upload to firestore?